# modal parent page refreshing on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a default state and 2 modal states.  When the modal is open and I go to another modal state the parent view is refreshing.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

```
.state 'main',
  url: '/main',
  templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl'
.state 'main.company',
  url: '/company',
  onEnter: ($modal) ->
    $modal.open
      templateUrl: '/views/company.html',
      controller: 'CompanyCtrl',
      animation: true,
      size: 'sm'
    return
 .state 'main.form',
   url: '/form',
   onEnter: ($modal) ->
   $modal.open
     templateUrl: '/views/form.html',
     controller: 'FormCtrl',
     animation: true,
     size: 'sm'
   return
```

Comment: Please post the code that takes you from one modal to another.

Comment: That's it, it can be by url or by $state.go('main.form');